# FS Node Delete All Files Except One that Matches Name

Tags: node.js, fs

I need to delete all files in a directory except for one that I have the name of. Let's say:

```
fs.unlink('./all except specialfile.txt', (err)) => {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log('file deleted!');
}
```

Comment: You'll probably need to read the list of files in the dir, then one at a time delete each, excluding your special file of course.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You have to get all files in the directory and then compare the name and delete the file if file name does not match your file

```
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');

fs.readdir('./', (err, files) => {
    if (err) {
        console.log(err);
    }

    files.forEach(file => {
        const fileDir = path.join('./', file);

        if (file !== 'specialfile.txt') {
            fs.unlinkSync(fileDir);
        }
    });
});
```